# Scrapy's System Performance Requirement?

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I am planning to create a website for price comparison of service provided by several companies. 
The main idea is visitor enter search requirement on the website and start searching, the crawl result display instantly on website rather than output as a file.

I am new to `python` and `scrapy`, not sure if `scrapy` can do this?

I am going to use it daily and even many times every day, and crawl on 30+ websites. I am afraid the search may overload the server? Can a shared web hosting support such crawling? Is there any system performance requirement?

Comment: Hi, why not using Scrapinghub's platform and API instead of assuming infrastructure costs?

Comment: Your biggest problems aren't Scrapy, it's that crawling by itself is a network-bound process, making it unseasonably slow. Crawling should always be a batch process - make only one or two crawls a day, and store the result in a database for users to query. Otherwise your customers will simply have to wait.

Comment: So crawling for highly volatile data is not doable? e.g. stock price...

Comment: @icantcode it's doable specially with scrapyd but it's highly unefficient